# Focus en un solo textbox de C#

Tags: c#

Buenos dias, tengo un problema con mis textbox. Tengo el focus para uno en especifico pero cuando intento diguitar en los otros se me activa en el que tengo el focus. Como puedo hacer de que el textbox que tengo el focus solo se active cuando escaneo (por que solo para eso lo ocupo). Este es mi codigo.

```
 private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtescaner.Focused)
        {
            txtescaner.Focus();
            txtescaner.Text += e.KeyChar;
            // Move el cursor al final
            txtescaner.SelectionStart = txtescaner.Text.Length;

            if (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || (char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar)))
            {
                e.Handled = false;

            }
            else if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Solo se permiten numeros", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                e.Handled = true;
                txtescaner.Clear();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Fijate q estas haciendo una pregunta atras de otra sobre el mismo problema.. primero preguntaste como poner el foco, ahora tienes problemas con ese mismo foco. me parece que tu solucion deberia venir por otro lado.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es por el if de la primer línea de codigo (`if (!txtescaner.Focused)`) ahi estas preguntando si ese textbox no se encuentra en focus. Al ser false entras y la segunda línea se pone en focus `txtescaner.Focus();` Deberias quitar el primer if

Comment: EStas en lo correcto. Sin embargo, si OP hace eso, va a perder funcionalidad que ya pidio antes. Tu respuesta sin embargo esta bien.

Comment: Claro igual me parece mal que el KeyPress este a nivel de form.

Answer (score 1):

Podria funcionar si pones los otros text box en el if

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtbox.Focused || txtbox2.Focused || txtbox3.Focused)
        {
            txtescaner.Focus();
            txtescaner.Text += e.KeyChar;
            // Move el cursor al final
            txtescaner.SelectionStart = txtescaner.Text.Length;

            if (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || (char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar)))
            {
                e.Handled = false;

            }
            else if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Solo se permiten numeros", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                e.Handled = true;
                txtescaner.Clear();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: no funciono. ..

Answer (score 0):

El evento que maneja el estado del focus se llama Form1_KeyPress, por lo que es posible que el error es que se lanza el evento cada vez que presionas una tecla dentro del formulario. (Se lanza el evento a nivel de formulario).

Asegúrate de que el evento lo lance el TextBox que debe.

Answer (score 0):

El evento esta a nivel de formulario, intenta cambiarlo por el evento especifico del texbox al que quieres validar asi evitaras lanzar el evento en cualquier control

Otra opción seria utilizar mascaras para validacion